# How to disable gulp-watch to copy all files on start task

Tags: gulp-watch

I have a gulp watch task like this:

```
gulp.src(devFiles, {base: gulpConfig.path.src})
  .pipe(watch(devFiles, {base: gulpConfig.path.src}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(gulpConfig.path.public + "/"))
```

The task it's working ok with one problem:
When I launch the task this will copy all files from source to destination.
How can I disable this behaviour: the copy files I want to be a different task, and this one just to watch files for changes.
In 99% the files are already there, so I don't need to copy again in destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution (inspired from gulp-watch docs):

```
watch(devFiles, {base: gulpConfig.path.src, ignoreInitial: true, verbose: true}, function (obj) {
        gulp.src(obj.path, {base: gulpConfig.path.src})
            .pipe(gulpConfig.path.public + "/");
    });
```

Where devFiles is an array of files masks, gulpConfig.path.src is source path, and gulpConfig.path.public is the destination folder.
I'm using this code from 2 days and work very well.
Now I didn't have to wait to finish loading all files on public folder at starting dev-watch task.